# East Europe (Poland?) dystopic, post-apocalyptic movie from the 70'-'80s

Tags: identify-this-movie

This is an old movie (about '70s-'80s) from East Europe (possibly Poland).

The main characters are two men (I think they were hibernated or something): they find themselves in this post-apocalyptic world in which only women survived, living undergroud. At the beginning the movie is funny, then it becomes evident that the society is a dictatorship and that people are oppressed; I remember that in order to control people there is this story: if you go out on the surface you die because of radiation, but the surface is actually safe (we find this out at the end).

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every detail of your description matches [Sexmission](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088083/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). The original title is *Seksmisja* and it's a Polish movie from 1984.

Here's a part of [plot description](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088083/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) from IMBD:

> Two scientists are chosen as guinea pigs for a time experiment: they are placed in hibernation and should be brought back to life after three years. In the meantime, however, the World War III breaks out and life have been wiped out of the surface of the Earth. When they wake up, it turns out that not only 50 years have passed but also that they are the only living specimens of the male sex in a new, underground society composed exclusively of women.

The movie has a cult status in Poland.